# Rich push in Urbanairship in android

Tags: android, push-notification, urbanairship.com

I am implementing Push Notification for Android in my project. I am implementing urbanairship GCM push Notification.While i gone through the urbanairship site, i camr to notice that under the messages tab, there is an option for "TEST RICH PUSH". I have already done tested simple push by sending push messages from "TEST PUSH" under the tab messsages. Now my question is in "TEST RICH PUSH", there are two new fields "USER" and "ALIAS". Is Rich push is used for sending push notification only to a particualar user currently using an App. or it has got any other purpose. Also please let me know how to enable "RICH PUSH" in their new website.(Earlier it is staright forward. Now i looked in their whole website, But i couldn't find a clue). Any help in this is highly appreciated.`

Thanks InAdvance

Answer (score 1):

Rich Push is automatically apart of the Urban Airship library (at least since 3.0.0 version, probably before then as well but I'm not sure which version number).  There are just a few things in code you have to do to get it up and started.

1. In your airshipconfig.properties file add the line "richPushEnabled = true" (without quotes).
2. In your manifest file add a service with the name "com.urbanairship.richpush.RichPushUpdateService" along with the PushService/PushWorkerService, etc.

And you should be good to go!  If not let me know I may have forgotten something.

To send a push you have to use the curl command found here (Under Rich Push -> Rich Push broadcast): https://support.urbanairship.com/customer/portal/articles/1069013-helpful-curl-examples under audience instead of doing "all", spit out this value to the logs somewhere once UA is initialized: RichPushManager.shared().getRichPushUser().getId() (import com.urbanairship.richpush.*;) and make sure the MasterSecret parameter is NOT your api secret but the master secret found in your API keys on your UA developer dashboard.

I wrote everything out because Urban Airship's documentation DNE for android Rich Pushes, it's absolutely horrible. They have a sample project but that's it.

Comment: The link provided is no longer valid.

Comment: @MikeOrtiz I updated the link. This is a different link and I didn't test to verify so if my information is incorrect please let me know. I do apologize for not testing I don't have my testing device on me this weekend.